Copy files looping with destination path based on source destination
I am using the following files/ organization for an Ansible project for src files to copy onto target (my roles all follow this scheme):
files/{{ ansible_distribution }}/etc/modules-load.d/i915.conf
files/{{ ansible_distribution }}/{{ host }}/etc/modules-load.d/i2c-dev.conf
files/etc/modules-load.d/tcp-bbr.conf

...

A src file belongs in any one of the the three directories above, respectively:
files/  
files/{{ ansible_distribution }}/
files/{{ ansible_distribution }}/{{ host }}/

Files in the first directory is intended for all target hosts managed. The second directory describes its files as specific to the group and the third directory describes its files as specific to the host. I use this naming scheme because it is easy to determine similarities and differences between configs in different hosts/groups.
They represents / on the target system, i.e. the target host should have the copied files to dest as:
/etc/modules-load.d/i2c-dev.conf
/etc/modules-load.d/i915.conf
/etc/modules-load.d/tcp-bbr.conf


How to loop over files to copy source files to the destination without hardcoding source and intended destination paths for each file? It can assume that I won't have both a version of e.g. i2c-dev.conf under host-specific files/{{ ansible_distribution }}/{{ host }}/ and under the more general group/all variants of the same files that coul

You can implement your project in just a few tasks.

Search locally (on the Ansible host) for the relevant files.
It is assumed here that all target paths begin with /etc/. If there are other path prefixes, these must still be implemented.

The target path is extracted from the source path, everything is saved together in a data structure

You can ensure the existence of the target directory.
If you know for sure that the target directory exists, you can also omit this task.

Copy the files to the target host


Code
- name: find files on Ansible host
  delegate_to: localhost
  find:
    paths:
      - "files/etc/"
      - "files/{{ ansible_distribution }}/etc/"
      - "files/{{ ansible_distribution }}/{{ inventory_hostname }}/etc/"
    recurse: yes
  register: result_find_files

- name: save relevant files as list
  set_fact:
    relevant_files: "{{ src_files | zip(dest_files) }}"
  vars:
    src_files: "{{ result_find_files.files | map(attribute='path') }}"
    dest_files: "{{ src_files | map('regex_search', '^files(/[\\w\\-]+){0,2}(?P<dest>/etc/.+)$', '\\g<dest>') | flatten }}"

- debug: var=relevant_files

- name: create directory if not exists
  file:
    path: "{{ item.1 | dirname }}"
    state: directory
  loop: "{{ relevant_files }}"

- name: copy relevant files to target host
  copy:
    dest: "{{ item.1 }}"
    src: "{{ item.0 }}"
  loop: "{{ relevant_files }}"


Task find files on Ansible host:
The task with the find module searches for all files in the specified paths. The search criteria can be adjusted as desired using the parameters of find, e.g. using patterns or excludes.

Task save relevant files as list:
The task generates a list of source-dest pairs. Source is accessible under .0 and Dest is accessible under .1.


Hint:

Using delegate_to: localhost the find task is explicitly executed on the Ansible host to search for the files locally and not on the remote host.

The relative path files/ is searched for starting from the playbook, if the whole thing is implemented in a role, it is searched for starting from the base directory of the role.

The debug: task is only to visualize the generated data structure.

The last two tasks (create directories and copy files) explicitly use loop: and not with_items: as otherwise the data structure would be changed using flatten, which must not happen here.


Result
TASK [find files on Ansible host] ***********************************************************************************************
ok: [test-ansible194 -> localhost]

TASK [save relevant files as list] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [test-ansible194]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test-ansible194] => {
    "relevant_files": [
        [
            "files/etc/modules-load.d/tcp-bbr.conf",
            "/etc/modules-load.d/tcp-bbr.conf"
        ],
        [
            "files/Ubuntu/etc/modules-load.d/i915.conf",
            "/etc/modules-load.d/i915.conf"
        ],
        [
            "files/Ubuntu/test-ansible194/etc/modules-load.d/my.conf",
            "/etc/modules-load.d/my.conf"
        ]
    ]
}

TASK [create directory if not exists] *******************************************************************************************
changed: [test-ansible194] => (item=['files/etc/modules-load.d/tcp-bbr.conf', '/etc/modules-load.d/tcp-bbr.conf'])
ok: [test-ansible194] => (item=['files/Ubuntu/etc/modules-load.d/i915.conf', '/etc/modules-load.d/i915.conf'])
ok: [test-ansible194] => (item=['files/Ubuntu/test-ansible194/etc/modules-load.d/my.conf', '/etc/modules-load.d/my.conf'])

TASK [copy relevant files to target host] ***************************************************************************************
changed: [test-ansible194] => (item=['files/etc/modules-load.d/tcp-bbr.conf', '/etc/modules-load.d/tcp-bbr.conf'])
changed: [test-ansible194] => (item=['files/Ubuntu/etc/modules-load.d/i915.conf', '/etc/modules-load.d/i915.conf'])
changed: [test-ansible194] => (item=['files/Ubuntu/test-ansible194/etc/modules-load.d/my.conf', '/etc/modules-load.d/my.conf'])

Example file structure in files dir:
files/
├── CentOS
│   └── etc
│       └── modules-load.d
│           └── q42test.conf
├── Ubuntu
│   ├── etc
│   │   └── modules-load.d
│   │       └── i915.conf
│   ├── test-ansible194
│   │   └── etc
│   │       └── modules-load.d
│   │           └── my.conf
│   └── test-client
│       └── etc
│           └── modules-load.d
│               └── i2c-dev.conf
└── etc
    └── modules-load.d
        └── tcp-bbr.conf

